# Make text responsively adjust to div to always fill it

Tags: html, css

I have tried different plugins and tutorials, but the problems is usually that they only adjust to the width of the div and/or that the div has size set in pixels and not responsive. But I want the text to always fill and fit the div and adjust the text based on text length and height/width of view, so that there is as little white spaces as possible. I have set the div to 100% both in height and width to fill the view. Anyone found a way to do this? Is it doable in just CSS, or do I need JS as well? Either a plugin, tutorial some guidance would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A common way I've 'scaled' text is by just setting the size based on `vh` or `vw`. If your `div` width is based on view width, then you can guarantee that the text will always look the same across resolutions.

```
.text{
    font-size: 0.1vw;
}
```

Comment: The same problem here since font size is based only on the view width. It won't make the font scale to fill the div.